# QGIS Assign point data to a line layer considering line direction

Tags: qgis, point, line

I have a line layer representing a river bank. The river bank is divided in numerous separate line features representing zones, each separate line has many vertices. The lines have a set direction.

I also have a points layer. The points are located at the start of each line (and therefore the end of the preceding line if following in the line direction). The points contain data.

I wish to assign the data associated with each point to the line segment following it, when considering the line direction.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this utilising QGIS?

Comment: Have you tried `join attributes by location`? If so, using which parameters and how does the outcome not suit your needs?

Comment: I have, but each point lies between two separate lines. So I need to be able to specify that the join occurs for the start of the desired line, not the end of the unwanted line. Only one of the lines is to share the data with a particular point.

Comment: I can see that somehow I need to be able to access the line geometry startpoint in a join operation but not sure how this can be achieved.

Comment: Each line has the start and end of its geometry in a specific orientation. In other words the start of one line is always at the end of the other. In doing more research, I feel the start of a solution may be to extract the use the field calculator to store X and Y of the start_point, then somehow use this.

Comment: The lines started out as one line and were divided using `SAGA Split lines at points`.

Comment: I have been able to add 2 columns to the line attribute table representing the x and y coordinates of the start of each line using `x(start_point($geometry))`. I feel I should be able now do a join against the points layer, but not sure how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a possibility of using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`

Let's assume there are five features in *'rivers'* (for simplification `"id"` is equal to `"Zone"`) and five features in *'some_points'* layer accordingly, where points are located at the start of each *'rivers'*'s feature, see image below.

[image: Original_data]

With the following query, it is possible *to assign the data associated with each point to the line segment following it, when considering the line direction.*

```sql
SELECT
    r.*,
    sp.DataField
FROM
    rivers AS r,
    some_points AS sp 
WHERE
    st_intersects(StartPoint(r.geometry),sp.geometry)
```

The output Virtual Layer will maintain initial attributes and geometries of *'rivers'* and additional field *"DataField"* from the *'some_points'* layer.

[image: Output]

Comment: thankyou @Taras, that seems to be exactly what I need, however I can't get that to work. I've even renamed my 2 layers to `rivers` and `some_points` and renamed one of the fields in `some_points` to `DataField`, but it throws up an error.

Comment: It's working now - I needed to clean up some data. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don’t forget to accept the answer if it solves your issue. Otherwise request for more solutions indicating your methodological requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach using the QGIS Field Calculator (if SQL and Virtual Layers are not your things - although personally, I'm a big fan).

Add a calculated field to the `'rivers'` layer:

```py
aggregate(layer:='some_points',
          aggregate:='max',
          expression:="DataField",
          filter:=intersects($geometry, start_point(geometry(@parent)))
          )
```

This will retrieve the maximum value (there should be only one anyway) of `"DataField"` from the `'some_points'` layer where the point intersects the first point of the `'rivers'` geometries.

This will only work in QGIS 3. If you want multiple values from the `'some_points'` layer you would need to add a calculated column for each one.

If you want lots of columns or need to support QGIS 2 the virtual layers from @Taras is the way to go.