# Attribute from point to line using end Vertex of a line - py console

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a line feature and a point feature. I would like to join the attribute of a point feature to the line feature based on end vertex, so when end vertex of a line falls on a point, the line feature gets the attribute of the 'point'(As show in the  Pic). Would like to know how to use py console. or is there a script already in place?
[image: Attribute from point to line]

Comment: In case if the script is not mandatory for you, please check this thread [QGIS Assign point data to a line layer considering line direction](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/323689/qgis-assign-point-data-to-a-line-layer-considering-line-direction/323696#323696). If you need some code, please check this [How to add vertex to an existing polyline programatically?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122800/how-to-add-vertex-to-an-existing-polyline-programatically?rq=1)